# How do I save treeview items into user_name(entry.get) and display them in another treeview

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I have a function where the user can checkout a book
[image: GUI]

```
   def checkout(self):
        global book_id
        global checkout_ids
        self.main_page.destroy()
        self.checkout_page = Tk()
        self.checkout_page.title("Checkout Page")
        self.checkout_page.config(padx=20, pady=20, bg="white")
        confirm_checkout_button = Button(text="CONFIRM AND CHECKOUT", fg=WHITE, bg=NAVY_BLUE, width=31,
                                         height=2, command=self.thank_you_page)
        confirm_checkout_button.grid(column=7, row=0, sticky="e")
        self.checkout_tree = ttk.Treeview()
        self.build_df = self.books_data.copy()
        df_column = self.books_data.columns.values
        self.checkout_tree["column"] = list(self.books_data.columns)
        self.checkout_tree["show"] = "headings"
        vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(orient="vertical", command=self.checkout_tree.yview())
        vsb.grid(column=8, row=1, sticky="ns")
        self.checkout_tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

        for column in self.checkout_tree['column']:
            self.checkout_tree.heading(column, text=column)
        for x in checkout_ids:
            build_df = self.build_df[self.build_df.IDENTIFICATION_NO == (x)]
            df_rows = build_df.to_numpy().tolist()
            for row in df_rows:
                self.checkout_tree.insert("", "end", values=row)

        self.checkout_tree.grid(column=0,row=1, columnspan=8)

        self.checkout_page.mainloop()
```

My plan was to save the book_ids to the user_name(entry.get) so the books will only display if it matches the user's entry
[image]

```
def return_book_page(self):
    self.borrow_or_return_page.destroy()
    return_page = Tk()
    return_page.title("Return page")
    return_page.config(padx=20,pady=20,bg=WHITE)
    list_of_books_to_return = Label(text="List of books to return: ", fg=NAVY_BLUE, bg=WHITE,
                                    font=("Viga", 32, "bold"))
    list_of_books_to_return.grid(column=0,row=1, sticky="w")
    please_text = Label(text="(Please check your library fines before returning the books)",
                        fg=NAVY_BLUE ,bg=WHITE, font=("viga", 12,))
    please_text.grid(column=0,row=2,sticky="w")
    check_fines = Button(text="LIBRARY FINES", fg=WHITE,bg=NAVY_BLUE, width=31,height=2,activebackground=NAVY_BLUE)
    check_fines.grid(column=3,row=2, columnspan=2)
    return_books = Button(text="RETURN BOOKS", fg=WHITE,bg="#6DA5A9", width=31,height=2, activebackground="#6DA5A9")
    return_books.grid(column=6,row=2, columnspan=2)

    self.return_book_tree = ttk.Treeview()
    self.build_df = self.books_data.copy()
    df_column = self.books_data.columns.values
    self.return_book_tree["column"] = list(self.books_data.columns)
    self.return_book_tree["show"] = "headings"
    vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(orient="vertical", command=self.return_book_tree.yview())
    vsb.grid(column=8, row=1, sticky="ns")
    self.return_book_tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
    borrow_dictionary = {
        self.name_login.get(): checkout_ids
    }

    for column in self.return_book_tree['column']:
        self.return_book_tree.heading(column, text=column)

        for x in borrow_dictionary[self.name_login.get()]:
            build_df = self.build_df[self.build_df.IDENTIFICATION_NO == (x)]
            df_rows = build_df.to_numpy().tolist()
            for row in df_rows:
                self.checkout_tree.insert("", "end", values=row)

    self.return_book_tree.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=8)
    return_page.mainloop()
```

I tried creating a dictionary called borrow_dictionary containing the user_name and the list of ids of the book the user has chosen but I get a key error everytime I save it to a csv or use it in a loop to display the values of the tree

```
borrow_dictionary = {
        self.name_login.get(): checkout_ids
    }

    for column in self.return_book_tree['column']:
        self.return_book_tree.heading(column, text=column)

        for x in borrow_dictionary[self.name_login.get()]:
            build_df = self.build_df[self.build_df.IDENTIFICATION_NO == (x)]
            df_rows = build_df.to_numpy().tolist()
            for row in df_rows:
                self.checkout_tree.insert("", "end", values=row)
```

How can I efficiently do this feature?

Comment: please [edit] your question and add the complete error traceback (starting from word "Traceback"), as well as a [mre]

Comment: I fixed the key error issue, now I'm wondering how do I save the dictionary containing the entry.get() and checkout_ids and have add another set of key(name):value(checkout_ids) and turn it into a csv that I can use to store data in the treeview

Comment: are you asking how to add a new `key: value` pair to a dictionary?

Comment: yes, and basically appending to the csv when a new user borrows and book and editing the same input when the same user borrows another one